# Entity Framework fires query to load related object although explicit loading for those objects is already done

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, query-optimization, dbcontext

I have these models and context in my application :

```
      public class Department
   {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set;}
     public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
   }

   public class Student
   {
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }

     public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
   }
 public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my code in Program.cs class :

```
   class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var context = new TestContext())
        {
            var students = context.Students.SqlQuery("Select * from dbo.Students").ToList();
            context.Departments.Load();

            Console.WriteLine(students[0].Department.Name); 
            Console.ReadLine(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Although related object - Department is loaded in the context by the line - **context.Departments.Load()**, still when the department name is printed in console entity framework fires a query in the database to fetch the related object. Shouldnt this query for related object fetching not be fired since the objects are already loaded in the context. ?

If i change the code to below -

```
            var students = context.Students.ToList(); 
            context.Departments.Load();

            Console.WriteLine(students[0].Department.Name);
```

Then when u access student[0].Department.Name , Ef doestnot fire a sql query to load department property.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - If i disable lazy loading , then it will give exception when related object is read. My point is since i have done explicit loading using context.departments.load() , there is no need for context to fire a query to load related object.

Comment: `context.Departments.Load()` doesn't mark the navigation property `student.Department` as loaded because the property itself isn't loaded explicitly. It's only *populated*, because EF executes what's called *relationship fixup*. That's why in this case disabling lazy loading would help.

Comment: @GertArnold - if i disable lazy loading, then it throws an error when it reads the department related property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently Change Tracker relationship fix-up doesn't work with the combination of Independent Associations and raw SQL queries.

To fix just add Foreign Key property to Student.  eg

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But EF does have a relationship manager, so it's able to fixup the relationships without FK property. Only in many-to-many relationships, relationship fixup doesn't occur because their are no junction table entities.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I repro'd this and fix-up didn't occur without the FK property, and Lazy Loading made no difference.

Comment: You're right. But I see now that it only happens when the students are fetched by a raw SQL query, even though in that case they're also attached to the context. Replacing the SQL query by `context.Students.ToList()` makes relationship fixup work. I wasn't aware of this difference.